# asp.net mvc date picker is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I did this example using the pluralsight video but the date picker is just not appearing.

1st. I created the template.

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,new {
    data_datepicker = true
});
```

2nd. I created the line in my .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
}
```

That should be all to make it work according to the video.

1. I am also including the jquery files of course

> ```
> > <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"
> > type="text/javascript"></script> <script
> > src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
> > type="text/javascript"></script> <script
> > src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")"
> > type="text/javascript"></script> <script
> > src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HR.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

The complete resulting html (resumed) seems fine:

```
<html><head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<form action="/ApplicantPosition/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    <fieldset>
      <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="appliedDate">Date applied</label>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-datepicker="True" data-val="true" data-val-required="Applied date is required" id="appliedDate" name="appliedDate" type="text" value="" />;

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When running on firefox/chrome, do you see any javascript error in the console?

Comment: I also found out that you forgot to add `);` at the end of your document ready function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the document ready function. Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
});
```

Notice the additional `);` at the end of my script which is missing in yours.

Comment: it works but the picker is transparent and I can see the other controls in the back. any idea?

Comment: @Luis, add the corresponding CSS. It's not bundled with ASP.NET MVC 3, you will have to download it or use a CDN which is even better: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`. There is also this one: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`. Of course there are other themes and colors. Up to you to pick the one you like. Take a look at the demos here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do:

```
$("input[data-datepicker='True']").datepicker();
```

if you are using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
I'd do:

```
$("input#appliedDate").datepicker();
```

edit - ther is an error in your function (you forgot the closing `);` )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#appliedDate").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: hey cool, thanks, is there a way to use a different theme? the picker is shown but it shows in top of other controls so I can see the days, but also the controls on the back.

Comment: there is an error in your document.ready(): look at my post i update it

Comment: it works but I still the controls in the back. the picker is transparent.